# Prove by induction that $3^{4n+2}+1$ is divisible by $5$ when $n \ge 0.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> Prove by induction that $3^{4n+2}+1$ is divisible by $5$ when $n \ge 0.$

(1) When $n=0$ we have that $3^2+1 = 10$ which is divisible by $5$ clearly.

(2) Assuming that the condition hold for $n=k.$

(3) Proving that it holds for $n=k+1$

$$3^{4(k+1) + 2} + 1 = 3^{4k + 6} + 1 = 3^4 \cdot 3^{4k+2} + 1$$

Since we assumed that $5 \mid 3^{4k+2} + 1$ we have that

$$3^4 \cdot 3^{4k+2} + 1 = 3^4 \cdot 5t, \text{ where $t \in \Bbb Z$}.$$

Thus $5 \mid 3^{4(k+1) + 2} + 1$.

Is this a valid proof? I'm not entirely sure I'm correct with this...

Comment: I don't understand how you show that $5\,|\,(3^{4k+2}+1)\implies 3^4\times 3^{4k+2}+1=3^4\times 5t$.  That would seem to be the critical step.

Comment: It is not valid. $3^43^{4k+2}+1=3^4(5t-1)+1$ since $3^4$ is not multiplied to the entire expression.

Comment: Notice that we assumed that $3^{4k+2} +1$ is divisible by $5$, and not $3^{4k+2}$. So, you'll need to sub-in $3^{4k+2} = 5t-1$ for some $t\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Non-inductive proof $3^{4n+2}+1=9^{2n+1}+1\equiv (-1)^{2n+1}+1=-1+1=0 \pmod {5}$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $3^4 \cdot 3^{4k+2} + 1= 3^4(3^{4k+2}+1)+1-3^4=3^4(3^{4k+2}+1)-80.$

Comment: Why the downvote ???

Answer (score -2):

An alternative strategy for this kind of problem is to consider the difference between consecutive terms.

Let $f(n)=3^{4n+2}+1$. Then $f(n+1)-f(n)=80 \cdot 3^{4 n + 2}$ is a multiple of $5$.

The claim follows by induction since $f(0)=10$ is a multiple of $5$.

(Actually, this proves that  $f(n)$ is always a multiple of $10$.)